# How to pass dropdown lists value id in controller in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

How to pass dropdown lists value id in controller in codeigniter.

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
```

with

```
$id = $this->input->post('dropdown name');
```

Comment: Not Getting the id value which I have pass it from drop down lists...$id = $this->input->post('viewname');
print_r($_POST);
die();

Comment: form method shoud be post

Answer (score 0):

use dropdown name at data post time. like.

//view page

```
 <select name="id">
    </select>
```

//controller
        $id=$this->input->post('id');

Comment: Still I am not getting the value of selection box... my view part is.  <select name="id" id="show">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

Comment: pls show how you are submitting form data. from view page.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
               $("#show").on('change',function() {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "<?php echo site_url('Dropdown/show_customers'); ?>",
                       success: function(data) {
                           $("#customers-list").html(data);
                       }
                   });
               });
               </script>

Comment: $this->load->library('table');      
          $this->table->set_heading('#', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email-ID', 'Credits');      
          $style = array('table_open'  => '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">');
          $this->table->set_template($style);
          $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->where('id','2');
  $query =  $this->db->get('customers');
    $data = $query->result_array();
echo $this->table->generate($data);

Comment: I want pass id value in  $this->db->where('id','2'), unable to get id value as  $this->db->where('id',$id);